# How to use Xcode 6 debugging for single C file

Tags: xcode

Xcode 6 has Run, build, pretty much everything in debug menu greyed out for a single C file that I open in Xcode. This is a prebuilt program. I wish to debug it, and make changes to the file, but it seems that it must be a project to use debug functionality. Is this true?

I am in university so I wish to have single files as they are submitted like that. If it is not possible to debug on Xcode, are there any better recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have project in order to be able to debug in Xcode. Xcode has to know how to compile/link/build Your files. You can make it very quickly by creating **Command line tool**. Go to `File` -> `New..` -> `Project...` <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. Choose **OS X** -> **Application** -> **Command Line Tool**. On the next screen choose language to be **C**. Then You'll have new project with **main.c** file where You can start coding and debugging.

Comment: To make it clearer you do not debug a file you debug a program that has been compiled from one or more files - so you have to tell Xcode about the program